# Python-Error installing python package (libmagic)

Tags: python, spyder

When I try to install `libmagic` using `pip install python-libmagic`, I get the following error:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Error 13] Permission denied: 'c:\users\*****\anaconda\Lib\site-pakages\_cffi_backend.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
>       Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

What should I do to rectify this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install the package to a system folder which you don't have permissions to write to.
You have two options(use only one of them):

1-setup a virtual env to install the package (recommended):

```
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate 
python -m pip install python-libmagic[samples]
```

2. install the package to the user folder:

```
python -m pip install --user python-libmagic[samples]
```

Comment: Your first option is wrong because the OP is on Windows, so there's no `source` available. Besides, he's using Anaconda, so the right recommendation is to use conda envirinments, not pip ones.

Comment: Glad to help. Accept the answer also